# Switch between two services in Angular2

Tags: angular

Let's say i have

```
import {ServerService} from './server-service'
import {ServerServiceMock} from './server-service-mock'
```

and

```
constructor (
    private serverService: ServerService
) {}
```

How would I switch programmatically lets say with a method, between both services? Needless to say there is lots of code depending on this.

Or maybe go into the services itself?

```
export class AuthZeroLockService {
    if buttonSwitch == true {
        return {//normalservice}
    } else {
        return {//mockedservice}
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using `provide(ServiceName, {useClass: ServiceMock})`?

Comment: What's the purpose? Can you please provide more context? "Mock" sounds like testing but there shouldn't be a need to switch programmatically.

Comment: Yes Testing for Dev purposes as we are in Dev stage of app, and need to mock backend when its down or wifi n/a.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `factory provider` to instantiate your service dynamically based on a value of the application.

The following example illustrates how to use a `factory provider`.

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AbstractDataService, DataService, MockedDataService } from './data.service';

let dataServiceFactory = (appService: AppService) => {
  // Example how to instantiate services conditionally
  return appService.State == 1 ? new DataService() : new MockedDataService();
};

export let DataServiceProvider = { 
  provide: AbstractDataService,
  useFactory: dataServiceFactory,
  deps: [AppService]
};
```

On your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `...`,
  providers: [AppService, DataServiceProvider] 
})
export class AppComponent { /* ... */ }
```

See the complete example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sweewerEULkFYAtQNM05).

Check Angular`s documentation about [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers) for more information.

Please let me know if this approach works for you.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying this

```
@Injectable
    export class AuthZeroLockService {
constructor (
    private serverService: ServerService, private mock: serverServiceMock
) {}
    getInstance()
    {
        if buttonSwitch == true {
            return {//normalservice}
        } else {
            return {//mockedservice}
        }
    }
    }
```

Now in your component.

```
service:IServerService // interface implemented by both service 
constructor (
    private serverServiceFactory: AuthZeroLockService
) {
//you can call below code whenever you want to switch by wrapping in a method. 
this.service = serverServiceFactory.getInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how you will use the service switching but could you not do something like this:

```
import {ServerService} from './server-service'
import {ServerServiceMock} from './server-service-mock'

export class myComponent {

private service:<any>;

constructor (
    private serverService: ServerService,
    private mockService: ServerServiceMock
) {

   this.switchService(true);

}

private switchService(mock:boolean){
      this.service = (mock)? this.mockService : this.serverService;
}

}
```

Comment: Thats how I ended up doing it before even looking at this answer.